# Question about pointer to array used in malloc/free

Tags: c

I saw the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(char n)
{
    int (*vals)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n]));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        (*vals)[i] = i;

    free(vals);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo(*(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

This lines makes me very uncomfortable:

```
free(vals);
```

`vals` is a pointer pointing to an array. This looks right, but I just have a difficult time internalizing it, I do not know why.

I am more used to the following style:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
......
free(p);
```

In this code, `p` is a pointer pointing to the start of a memory region for some integers, the malloc and free are symmetric in that they both work on a pointer type; yet the original code has `malloc()` working on a pointer to an array and `free()` a pointer.

Out of curiosity, I modified the original code:

```
free(vals);  ==>  free(*vals);
```

I was expecting this change will fail at compiler, the reason is `*vals` is an array now. But gcc is fine and valgrind does not complain memory leak.

I know C has a thing called array degenerates to pointer at function call. But I just cannot internalize this stuff. Sorry writing so long to describe a problem, wish you could see my struggle. Is there a definitive doc/stackoverflow/blog to clear this up - best C99 or later?

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, more than anything else, I find it more odd that the choice of magnitude type is a platform `char`.

Comment: I *feel* like something is wrong here. `vals` looks like a pointer to an array, therefore it is essentially of type `int**`, but the code allocates `n` `int`s of memory to it, whereas I think it should have allocated for a pointer. Maybe I am missing the point, but the code doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You say, *"makes me very uncomfortable"* and I can sympathize. It seems to me that the driving force behind the coder's choice of syntax was *precisely* to make any future readers "feel very uncomfortable".

Comment: ... and clang's static analyser isn't comfortable, either: *note: Result of 'malloc' is converted to a pointer of type 'int[n]', which is incompatible with sizeof operand type 'int[n]'*

Comment: @aulven. The type of pointer to an array is `int(*)[n]`, not `int**`. Arrays are not pointers. The code is both correct and efficient though a bit non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

writing `free(*vals);` is same as writing `free(vals);`

edited your code to clear that a little bit

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char n)
{
    int (*vals)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n]));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        (*vals)[i] = i;

    printf("*val is %p\n", *vals);
    printf("val is %p\n", vals);
    printf("&val is %p\n", &vals);
    
    free(vals);
}

int main()
{
    foo(10);
    
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
*val is 0000018190365d50
val is 0000018190365d50
&val is 0000005d9dbff7b8
```

note that `vals` is Array pointer which means that its base type is **an array of n integers** where the pointer `val` is created in that stack and points to the whole array, not the first element only and that array is created in the `heap`, to illustrate, look at the following graph:

[image]

so for example if you write:

```
printf("val is %p\n", vals);
printf("val+1 is %p\n", vals+1);
```

the output will be :

```
val is 00000207ef0c5d50
val+1 is 00000207ef0c5d78
```

note the difference between the 2 is about **40** bytes as `val` points to the whole array not only one element as in case of `int *p = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));`

note that when I say it points to the whole array, I also mean it points to the base address of the array.

in case of `*Vals`, look at the next graph:

[image]

`*Vals` is just an address of the first element of the array which is by the way is same as the base address of the array.

refer to [free() manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free), they said:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
> must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or
> realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before,
> undefined behavior occurs. If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

and what does `malloc()` function return ?

it returns the base address of your reserved space in heap, so writing `free(vals);` is same as writing `free(vals);`

Answer (score 0):

This codes uses *dynamic VLA*.
I think that it may be easier to understand if the code is reformulated with a `typedef`.

```
void foo(char n)
{
    typedef int T[n];
    T *vals = malloc(sizeof(T));

    ...
  
    free(vals);
}
```

Now it looks like a tivial use of a single dynamic object.

To access elements of an array first the pointer has to be dereferenced `*vals` forming an array, which decays to `int*` pointer suitable for `[]` operator.